# Remove class from the next 5 items on button click?

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to click the 'show-more' button and remove the class 'hidden' from the 'news-item' div, and thus, have 5 more news-items show when the button is clicked. How do I implement my code remove the 'hidden' class on 5 more news-items?

```
$('.show-more').click(function () {
$('.news-item').removeClass('hidden');
}
```

Comment: If you add your relevant HTML this question will, likely, receive faster, better answers specific to your problem. Without that, you're likely to get guesses. Which are rarely well targeted to your specific situation. Please see the "[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" guidelines for further advice.

Comment: Also be more specific about behavior wanted. How many are there and does this need to increment for example. Well formed questions with proper details get well formed answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never done it, but i think you could use jQuery [slice](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) function...search for all your hidden elements and change class... note that using lt could be more expensive as it is said on jquery documentation page...

i made this jsfiddle to check it out...https://jsfiddle.net/vp9fxcc7/

```
function fnShow()
{
$( ".hiddenC" ).slice( 0,2 ).addClass("showC");
    $( ".hiddenC" ).slice( 0,2).removeClass("hiddenC");
}
```

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you :) The slice method is really effective

Answer (score 1):

Use the [:lt](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector and [:hidden](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) selector.

```
$(".news-item:hidden:lt(5)").show()
```

So it will get the first 5 hidden elements with the class of news-item. Also I would recommend using the show function.

Comment: Doesn't make sense calling `show()` on items that are already `:visible`

Comment: oops my mistake. Changed visible to hidden.

Comment: Is there another way to do this without the It selector? My jQuery doesn't support it and I don't want to change that version

Comment: @sk_225 The `lt` selector has been in jQuery since version 1. It was updated in 1.8 but that was only to prevent negative values. You should be able to use it no matter the version.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to first target the div via the class name or id, check to see if it is hidden, if it is hidden then simply use the lt to get the next number of elements.

Here is my jsFiddle example : https://jsfiddle.net/zgkj53kd/

Html

```
<button type="button" class="display-more">Show more</button>
<div class="divContent">1</div>
<div class="divContent hidden">2</div>
<div class="divContent hidden">3</div>
<div class="divContent hidden">4</div>
<div class="divContent hidden">5</div>
<div class="divContent hidden">6</div>
<div class="divContent hidden">7</div>
<div class="divContent hidden">8</div>
<div class="divContent hidden">9</div>
<div class="divContent hidden">10</div>
<div class="divContent hidden">11</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(function () {
    $('.hidden').hide();

    $('.display-more').on('click', function () {
        $(".divContent:hidden:lt(5)").show()
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there another way to do this without the It selector? My jQuery doesn't support it and I don't want to change that version –